# Error recuperar variable tipo date

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Quiero recuperar la solo la fecha y mostrarla en el campo del formulario.
El fallo que tengo es cuando recupero la variable la obtengo en tipo string y la transformo en date, incluso después de la transformación no la veo en el formulario.

Adjunto imagenes del formulario y de los console.log que hago.

[image: Formulario]
[image: Console.log]

El error que tengo ahora es que no recupera la misma fecha cuando convierta la fecha.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
fila = $(this).closest("tr");
dataBD = fila.find('td:eq(6)').text();

dataconvert = new Date(dataBD);
data = dataconvert.toISOString().split('T')[0];

console.log(data);
console.log(dataconvert);

$("#data").val(data);
```

Comment: Debes agregar el html del input para saber como se llama tu input y como tratas de cargarlo en realidad}

Answer (score 1):

Usando el método [**`toISOString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) lo obtendrías, por ejemplo:

```js
var data = new Date();
var actual = data.toISOString().split('T'); // => tengo ["2023-01-06","14:21:01.467Z"]
console.log(actual)
```

Entonces, obtengo el primer elemento del array, ya que eso solo me interesa:

```js
var data = new Date();
var actual = data.toISOString().split('T')[0]; // => tengo "2023-01-06"
console.log(actual)
```

Y luego siguiendo en base a tu problema, sería:

```js
var data = new Date();
var actual = data.toISOString().split('T')[0];
$("#data").val(actual);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="date" id="data">
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me has ayudad pero tengo el problema que la fecha que recupero y la que se convierte no son la misma. Adjunto captura de pantalla arriba.

Comment: He actualizado el codigo en la descripción de la pregunta

Comment: porque envías 1 parámetro en `Date(dataBD)`? qué significa eso? prueba con `new Date();`

Comment: Funciona con el dia de hoy pero yo quiero ver en el campo date la fecha que recupero con la variable dataBD y me devuelve un tipo string haci 06-01-2023.

Comment: a `dataBD` puedes reformatearlo con este regex => `let regex = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/;` y usarías replace en este caso => `let data = dataBD.replace(regex, "$3-$2-$1");` y lo que obtienes lo asignas a tu valor del input => `$("#data").val(data);`, ya no sería necesario usar el `toISOString` para asignar el valor al input.